# Launchd Bash and Node

Tags: node.js, bash, macos

I have a script as a .plist registered in /Library/LaunchDaemons - on a particular IO event, this script triggers a bash script that lives in /usr/local/bin (root:admin 0755).

Bash script runs a nodejs script

This is the bash script:

```
if [[ $(ioreg -p IOUSB | grep Realforce -c) > 0 ]]; then
  echo "Realforce is present"
  echo 1
  echo $(node ./lgtvcontrol/TVinputChange.js mac)
  echo 2
else
  echo "Realforce not detected"
fi
```

When I run the bash script as root I get this output:

```
Realforce is present
1
mac 3166798437680e8a22c7093bf294fbaf connecting connected app com.webos.app.hdmi3
2
```

When the bash script runs through the LaunchDaemon with UserName root, it gets this output:

```
Realforce is present
1

2
```

I don't get why LaunchDaemon fails to run the node script. Any idea or experience with this?

Thank you!!!

---

Edit 1:
By adding the following key to the plist, I'm able to get an error in node now.

```
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/lgtvcontrol</string>
    </dict>
```

When outputting the node error log to a file, I get this on execution:

```
internal/validators.js:113
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:113:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1039:7)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/bin/lgtvcontrol/node_modules/persist-path/index.js:9:27)
    at new LGTV (/usr/local/bin/lgtvcontrol/index.js:48:16)
    at LGTV (/usr/local/bin/lgtvcontrol/index.js:38:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/lgtvcontrol/TVinputChange.js:7:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: Could the path `./lgtvcontrol/TVinputChange.js` differ? What's the working directory of the script when it gets executed? What's the exit code of the node invokation? Anything in stderr? Try adding `set -e` at the start and see if 2 ever gets printed.

Comment: Why are you using `echo $(node ...)` instead of just running `node ...` directly? See [shellcheck message SC2005](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2005).

Comment: @cbr I tried expressing full path, same result - `set -e` resulted in the same output

Comment: @GordonDavisson doesn't make a difference, I was trying to see if I could get an output from node written out, but nothing shows up